# Django Error: Reverse for 'image_upload' with no arguments not found?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass primary key as URL argument from CreatePost to UploadImage view but I'm constantly getting an error even if I see primary key in URL. I'm new to Django, so please help me :)
**views.py**

```
    class CreatePost(CreateView):
    model=shopModels.UserPost
    template_name='shop/create_post.html'
    fields='__all__'
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['category'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        form.fields['category'].widget.attrs['oninvalid']="this.setCustomValidity('Ovo polje je obavezno!')"
        return form
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
        return super(CreatePost, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('image_upload',kwargs={'user_post':self.object.id})
    
class UploadImage(CreateView):
    model=shopModels.Image
    template_name='shop/images_upload.html'
    fields='__all__'
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return reverse('login')
        return super(UploadImage, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**
...

```
path('create_post/',views.CreatePost.as_view(),name="create_post"),
path('image_upload/<int:user_post>',views.UploadImage.as_view(),name="image_upload"),
```

...

**models.py**

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user=models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
text=models.TextField(null=True)
category=models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
is_used=models.BooleanField(default=False)
price=models.IntegerField(default=0)
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.user)
def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
    return reverse('image_upload', kwargs={'user_post':self.id})
    

class Image(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     user_post=models.ForeignKey(UserPost,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='images/')
     def __str__(self):
        return self.user_post.title
     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')
```

**EDIT!!!**

```
NoReverseMatch at /image_upload/23
```

Reverse for 'image_upload' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['image_upload/(?P<user_post>[0-9]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/image_upload/23
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'image_upload' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['image_upload/(?P<user_post>[0-9]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\marij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\marij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3

Comment: The error in the title of your post does not match what your code is. Can you please include the full stacktrack? Currently your code supplies kwargs to reverse, but the error says no arguments were provided. Something's not lining up.

Comment: I just edited a post. I guess that this is a dumb question but I'm really new in Django and really confused.. The error says that no argument is provided but I see id in url

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not including `user_post` key in html form, you should include it in jinja  style

`<a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'image_upload' user_post=user_post_key %}">`

And if you want to do some operations based on that `user_post` You should override the  `form_valid(self)` method and access the `int:user_post` by using `self.kwargs['user_post']`.

Comment: I've tried to override form_valid method and it didn't help. The problem is that I don't have any <a> tag in Jinja template that leads to this url. It works like this: When I create a post in CreatePost view it automatically passes id of the post that's created to the UploadImage view (at least it should). I see id in url but I don't get what's happening then with the argument...

Answer (score 0):

Your path explicitly expects and integer for user_post:

```
 path('image_upload/<int:user_post>',views.UploadImage.as_view(),name="image_upload"),
```

If you call reverse(...) and you handover 123 you meed to make sure that 123 is a type integer and not e.g. string.